# How to retrieve events from an online ics file in android?

Tags: android, http, icalendar

I'm currently looking for a solution to access to an ics online file by http request to use it in my application. I have an idea to do that but I don't know how to that. I think I have to make a get request (maybe with httpURLconnection...) to download the ics file and save it and then use it as I want in my activity. I have tried this way in a onClick method in my button listener :

```
try {
    //this is the file you want to download from the remote server
    String path = "http://.../file.ics";
    //this is the name of the local file you will create
    boolean eof = false;
    URL u = new URL(path);
    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setDoOutput(true);
    c.connect();
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("data/edt.ics"));
    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len1 = 0;
    while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
    }
    f.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it creates this error in the logcat :

```
06-02 15:29:05.260 6685-6685/com.enib.enibapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.enib.enibapp, PID: 6685
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
        at com.enib.enibapp.ui.home.HomeFragment$1.onClick(HomeFragment.java:74)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

And I don't understand this stacktrace...

The purpose is to retrieve events from ics file to display events you have during the journey. I've already searched a solution to manipulate ics file and I found iCal4j library. But the retrieve part is one of my issues. Could someone help me or give me clues?

PS:If there is some problem in my question, do not hesitate to report me the issue, I am new in addition to begin the android development

Comment: Since no  one else has commented, I'll chip in (not android expert). WRT to fetching the file, the fact that it's an ics file may not be the cause - it should not be any different from an any other get request.  So focus on how to successfully fetch a file first.  Google the error message and see if anything relates.   Also make sure the file is publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your advise @anmari. After some in-depth researches, I found the problem's explanation : the connection request must be placed in a doInBackground method of an AsyncTask's child. So I place the code that I used below if someone who is in the same situation that I was needs a solution.

The AccesHTTP Class:

```
public class AccesHTTP extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private Controle controle;
    private String urlServ = null;
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    public AccesHTTP(String servaddr) {
        controle = Controle.getInstance(null);
        urlServ = servaddr;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        // Create a TimeZone
        System.setProperty("net.fortuna.ical4j.timezone.cache.impl", MapTimeZoneCache.class.getName());

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlServ);
            Reader r = null;
            r = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "ISO-8859-15");
            CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
            Calendar thisCalendar = builder.build(r);
            controle.refreshEdt(thisCalendar);
        } catch (IOException | ParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Completed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s){
        Log.d("Return","************ " + s + " ************");
        if(s!=null){
            delegate.processFinish(s);
        };
    }
}
```

The AccesDistant Class:

```
public class AccesDistant implements AsyncResponse {
    //constant
    private static final String SERVERADDR = "https://.../calendar.ics";

    public AccesDistant() {
        controle = Controle.getInstance(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {
        if(output.equals("Completed")){
            Log.d("Completed", "*******************");
        } else {
            Log.d("Erreur null return", "*******************");
        }
    }

    public void envoi() {
        AccesHTTP dataAccess = new AccesHTTP(SERVERADDR);
        //delegate link
        dataAccess.delegate = this;
        //server call
        try {
            dataAccess.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Erreur send request","******************" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```